# How to Read array of multiple object in Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Return Server Side:

```
 echo json_encode($result, true);
```

response to ajax

```
[{name:object},{name:object},{name:object},{name:object},{name:object}]
```

I am trying to read value

```
alert(result.value);
```

Comment: What exactly is your question here? Are you asking how to look over each object in the array and alert the name property? What does result look like?

Comment: `result.name` it should do it

Comment: yes i am trying to result.name but could't be get result